# Is loose-leaf cabbage just as prone to cabbage worms as headed cabbage?

Tags: pests, cabbage

Is loose-leaf cabbage generally just as prone to cabbage worms as headed cabbage?

We've had trouble with cabbage worms on regular green cabbage that forms heads (the worms seem to hide inside the heads). I was wondering if they would be less of a problem in loose-leaf cabbage, since there wouldn't be tight spots for them to hide, and since you maybe harvest from them periodically, depending.

I've already heard they can be less of a problem in Chinese cabbage, and purple cabbage. So, I found this [chartreuse-colored loose-leaf Chinese cabbage](https://www.rareseeds.com/chirimen-hakusai-chi/) (it's hard to find purple Chinese cabbages), and then I got this question in my head, since it just looks like it might be less prone. So, I'm wondering if these types of cabbage would be good to plant where cabbage worms would normally attempt to infest.

Edit: To clarify, know that this is about the loose-leaf quality of the cabbage (not whether or not it's Chinese cabbage).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they will still be a problem - cabbage worms (or larvae of the cabbage white butterfly, which is what they are) like any member of the cabbage family or brassicas in general, and your chinese cabbage is a member of that family.

If you have room, try planting cabbages elsewhere in the garden and grow something else in the space usually allotted to them. Companion planting might help - plants like garlic or any of the onion family planted nearby will help to deter them, more information on that and other natural methods here https://dengarden.com/gardening/Natural-Ways-To-Control-Cabbage-Worms

If all fails, row covers (cloches), the type with closed ends, will keep them off.